# dkim=fail but I set dkim for selector mail and it's resolvable

Tags: email, dkim, opendkim

I have a mail server which was working with no issue, but this night suddenly my emails are sent to spam folder.

This is `dig +short txt mail._domainkey.my-domain.com.`:

```
"v=DKIM1; h=sha256; k=rsa;" "p=MIICIjANBgkqhkiG9w0BAQEFAAOCAg8AMIICCgKCAgEA0v6tpFJ/tylfYek2c18DKiAlOG22/39J9LRQGKPUJmu0cZJTocF1BBHOV5CsHV1zgLL9qm3Az+04eHYHT+6n9a+xZbjwDQcadaRb63OFqdA8fXIXrOh/nCqu7lnc/N63Xkf5KMZjSo1d66fDWjK00SeT7jzR1ZpkLX532pVp22O8/LMui3gi4h62RTO604TvicpfC0EcyYWAND" "EdMTdz0jyatBQ3Je6ABF+3+bJn6LEyaFx+PCiwCQdyW/w25agEAcjZ3WamIpBcHaPX4mQrnBnIJd1e1IpnpuJ30rT6ysDvggM9aNd+20iyA4XkaR6tYP4ssCmgP6RG99XQpKIVVvfD1okz0y80Jh3n3zbU4V7MkXrgxxL0A3/cifTxx4MxxaSeRxN+U0+iMLWA9JmOx5A9W2MqAxWRhouQoYYzzDzgwncElJTkmVR1KmWc7c7IP8cl+Ogr" "qPUItGla2p/HbKy6t4oaaBqfeCXKqh162PvlIk+cBkshaCmiFRTJgCUAARKJMBNwgT/sSGNMlv00eAMzTsvtbRmjG3vqP/I864FotR/CoLo9jIgH3XNViXSLg1xLYhLFDv2FTl1xPKkOdRLMfe6pdrHjVx242JMq8USIu/XGW8xy3NS7hhmRPJwwduqIVjNqC70pxpi3Kr06oP5KxXIoQi4KkkzzkIRJntsCAwEAAQ=="
```

This is also `dig +short txt default._domainkey.my-domain.com.`:

```
"v=DKIM1; h=sha256; k=rsa;" "p=MIICIjANBgkqhkiG9w0BAQEFAAOCAg8AMIICCgKCAgEAvMLFzeNuFkHMFs683mRXWSQ+2izGqayRkWvJ+9XMLTnMhPtO5HsFFGObgtZ419J+HtyvDdLJaCWgJn8bra0aQAADln9Jm216MAznixIOLFzFmJ5gmQ0J6H1VglTZG8r3iIyFV7da4BKjAry2Nut51ie/68DRSBVO+DvSDk+hNamRDR+kOPq6yLXwt7Xbma9SxklIGmpK6lYi/n" "Ie34zAm0xjU2SbA7bupLXUBOh12hqQOPlmIF9+RTYr3Yl1mEtFXwtPYf1EiwHTTUl9M7o3MrD0GZ5MiFede3tuiY153uackhsFWNuTViq8c6llveO4Go1NXEvdwrbED3jmTWpRULMP57cwwJJYGRWrNn58gTSZdy3ziL1JGPink4LKsTcBio1PhBKP/tR28y/1ZfMoTzooSTGyTYAAWv0EBbfOElgsUKcfqaKiEGOzagc9FXZQiuqzHIl1" "kqzwC8mx5TJV8l+rIqwcgSGswt5u01l7oAAtxXECEu8cR4/UcvY5v2zSGT5Mp5WZFOgrjKn1LKvu/u6Vdxn7V8YH1t/h2vr7/xCX7Z7DOvdr12V+PWur80g9ZLCiNghYLF5sBz9KSkZIZBYtXumDchVc6WOlw7daxaoZ/qI58pwtf0KGMak93C+0jqqF82GkpwhoelOSe7l8tQ/sFV6tJLxPkWPSmkge50UCAwEAAQ=="
```

Both these two keys are correct, I copied from mail server where these public keys are generated.

This is the log of my mail server:

```
DKIM-Signature field added (s=mail, d=my-domain.com)
```

But this is what I see in Gmail:

```
dkim=fail header.i=@my-domain.com header.s=mail header.b=hDJDvRR8;
```

Am I doing anything wrong here? Everything used to work properly, but suddenly I faced this issue and not sure what's wrong with what.

Comment: You need to look at the `DKIM-Signature` lines in the email header for some help. The selector used id `mail`, so it would appear that the `default` key may not be in use and if so, could be removed. I'd also increase verbosity for opendkim. I would rather regenerate the keys that reuse them from another server.

Comment: @Bib thanks, I'll try regenerating the key. The emails are delivered, but either inbox or spam. They're not rejected. I doubt if DNS Server faced some issue which needs investigating.